# Bash Script To Add A Folder/Directory to the path in linux not working

Tags: linux, bash, backtrack-linux

I created a bash script to add 
`/My_Scripts/Bash_Scripts`
to the default PATH of linux.

```
!/bin/bash
#This Script is used to add a folder/diectory to the PATH..


echo -e "\e[92m\e[1mCREATING PATH...........\n\n"
cd
mkdir My_Scripts
cd My_Scripts
mkdir Bash_Scripts
cd

export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/My_Scripts/Bash_Scripts
echo -e "\e[92m\e[1mPATH CREATON SUCCESSFUL\n \e[39m"
echo $PATH
```

The output of script is

```
root@kali:~/Desktop# bash add_path
CREATING PATH...........


PATH CREATON SUCCESSFUL

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/My_Scripts/Bash_Scripts'
```

but if I type `echo $PATH` in the terminal outside, the path is not added

```
root@kali:~/Desktop# $PATH
bash: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing - you should use `echo $PATH`. By simply typing `$PATH` you're trying to execute the command, hence the "No such file or directory error"

Next - the `/root/My_Scripts/Bash_Scripts` wasn't really added to the `PATH`. The first output you see in done inside the script, so the changes could be seen there.

The reason is that `PATH` will be set only in the context of the script shell, execute it as `source  add_path` to preserve the changes in variables (but only for current shell).

If you want the variable to be persistant in all shells - add it to `/.bashrc` (since you're runnung as root).

Comment: Thank you for replying ... Now i seem to understand the problem..
But i dont know how to automate it..
Can U Please tell me what changes i have to make in my script to automate it

Comment: Append it to some file and source this file (or export from it)  in your .bashrc script. This way the change will be permanent

Comment: Sir i am new to bash. and i dont know how to do it...
so can u please write a bash script which copies /My_Scripts/Bash_Scripts to .bashrc

Comment: It seems you have installed Kali linux. If it was on purpose - you kinda need to learn bash and linux basics first before you proceed. So I higly recommend you to look into the manuals and to try things by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your changes is affected in current shell only.Put the  entry in .bashrc file. It will affect the all the terminal.open the .bashrc file and add the below line and run the file -

```
 vim ~/.bashrc
 export PATH="$PATH:/home/username"
 ~/.bashrc
```

**Edit the parent shell**

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash 
export "PATH=$PATH:$HOME/My_Scripts/Bash_Scripts"
echo $PATH
```

$~ PATH=$(./script.sh)

$~ echo $PATH

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/loganaayahee/My_Scripts/Bash_Scripts
```

Comment: Thank you sir for replying...
Please tell me what changes should i make to automate my script

Comment: open the .bashrc file and append the path . Ex - export PATH="$PATH:/home/New_pathname" save the file and   run  -         bash  .bashrc

Comment: sir can u write a bash script whih does just that

Comment: Are you able to open the .bashrc file

Answer (score 1):

You are starting up a new bash process and `PATH` is only modified in the context of the new process. When this process quits, changes done in its environment do not propagate to the parent process.

Instead, you would want to modify `PATH` in the context of current bash process. If you want this temporarily, you may [`source`](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x237.html) your script. `source` will run in the context of the current bash process. Beware of any side effects - like `cd` will change the directory, `exit` will terminate the current bash process.

If you want this change permanently for all future interactive sessions, you can modify `~/.bashrc`.

Also, the syntax of [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is `#!/path/to/program`, you are missing a `#`.

Comment: Thank you for replying.. Now that i know what caused the problem.
Can u please tell me what changes should i make in the  script so that i can use it permanently for future interactive sessions..

Comment: Include `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/My_Scripts/Bash_Scripts` in your .bashrc.

Comment: sir i am new to bash programming ..can u please tell me the whole script

Comment: Everyone starts new. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html and google is your best friend :)

Comment: sir no luck in googling it  so can u please write a bash script which copies /My_Scripts/Bash_Scripts to .bashrc